# Only one seq column to generate ID in R

Tags: r

I have data only have one column No. I want to assign id to each set of seq like 
first seq `1 2 3 4` assigned 1 , second seq `1 2 3` assigned 2 , third seq `1 2 3 4 5 6` assigned 3.  does anyone have idea how to make it in R . thanks

```
df <- data.frame(No = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `diff` function to check the break point where a descending order happens and a `cumsum` on the result will create an id for each ascending sequence, since the first element will always be in the first sequence and in order to compensate the length decreasing from `diff` function, you need to prepend 0 or 1 to the sequence depending on if you want the group to start from 0 or 1:

```
cumsum(c(0, diff(df$No) < 0))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2

cumsum(c(1, diff(df$No) < 0))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence is ordered, we can just get the logical index by checking for 1 and then get the cumulative sum.

```
cumsum(df$No == 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

---

Or a faster option is `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := cumsum(No - shift(No, fill = No[1]) <= 0)]
```